# Select values if doesn't match in other table by left join

Tags: mysql

I am having some problem with getting the values from two tables of my database .
I have two tables in my database 1 is mem and 2nd is payment 
mem stores name and drawid of users
payment table stores draw and instalment of the user

User pays us every month .
so if a user with a draw id 1 pays us in feb the values in two tables are 
mem drawid=1 and name = something
payment draw = 1 and instalment=2

drawid in mem is same as draw in payment

so the tables has many to many relation.
Now I need to find the list of all the members who have not paid even 1 instalment before 4th month.

I am using this query

```
 SELECT drawid,contact,dnd,mem.name, count(*) as numPayments FROM mem 
 LEFT JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw) GROUP BY 
 drawid HAVING numPayments < 4
```

it's working all good no issues only the issue is that I also need to show the instalments the user has paid so I need to fetch all the instalment from table payments and then show by while loop.

This query is perfect but it gives me repeated results !!!

```
  SELECT drawid,contact,dnd,mem.name, count(*) as numPayments,NULL numPaidPayments ,NULL PAID_CONTACT,NULL NAME_PAID FROM mem 
LEFT JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw) GROUP BY 
drawid HAVING numPayments < 4
UNION
SELECT NULL drawid,NULL contact, NULL dnd, NULL name,NULL numPayments,COUNT(*) as numPaidPayments ,contact PAID_CONTACT,mem.name NAME_PAID  FROM mem 
INNER JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw) GROUP BY 
drawid HAVING numPaidPayments >= 4
```

Comment: you have error  .. ?   . worng result  ?  ... update your post add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: i dont have any error this query is working good, i just want this query to also give me the list of paid instalments by user.

Comment: Give us some sample data and corresponded result.

Comment: In your previous version of this question you inferred that the member could elect the month the payment is for and that he could pay in advance, in arrears or on time - or any combination of these states. Is this still the case?

Comment: yes correct , user can elect the month and pay in advance too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT drawid,contact,dnd,mem.name, count(*) as numPayments,NULL numPaidPayments ,NULL PAID_CONTACT,NULL NAME_PAID FROM mem 
    LEFT JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw) GROUP BY 
    drawid HAVING numPayments < 4
    UNION
    SELECT NULL drawid,NULL contact, NULL dnd, NULL name,NULL numPayments,COUNT(*) as numPaidPayments ,contact PAID_CONTACT,mem.name NAME_PAID  FROM mem 
    INNER JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw) GROUP BY 
    drawid HAVING numPaidPayments >= 4
```

Try above query.

Comment: This is giving me kind of best result but the issue is also giving me blank rows too !!

Comment: Actually, i have repeated results :(

Comment: please suggest me , you gave me the answer but this needs to be updated ... :( can your help me plz

Comment: Still same issue . i am getting blank results too!

Answer (score 0):

Given this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from member;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from payment;
+--------+------+
| mem_id | mth  |
+--------+------+
|      1 |    1 |
|      1 |    2 |
|      1 |    3 |
|      1 |    4 |
|      2 |    1 |
|      2 |    3 |
|      3 |    2 |
|      3 |    4 |
+--------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This

```
select m.id, group_concat(p.mth order by p.mth) mthspaid,
        sum(case when p.mem_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) NoofMthsPaid,
        4 - sum(case when p.mem_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) NoofMthsMissed
from member m
left join payment p on p.mem_id = m.id
group by m.id
```

Gives this

```
+------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| id   | mthspaid | NoofMthsPaid | NoofMthsMissed |
+------+----------+--------------+----------------+
|    1 | 1,2,3,4  |            4 |              0 |
|    2 | 1,3      |            2 |              2 |
|    3 | 2,4      |            2 |              2 |
|    4 | NULL     |            0 |              4 |
+------+----------+--------------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if you add in code to work out the months due

```
select paid.*, due.mthsmissed
from
(
select m.id, group_concat(p.mth order by p.mth) mthspaid,
        sum(case when p.mem_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) NoofMthsPaid,
        4 - sum(case when p.mem_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) NoofMthsMissed
from member m
left join payment p on p.mem_id = m.id
group by m.id
) paid
left join
(    
select due.id, group_concat(due.mth order by due.mth) MthsMIssed
from
(        
select m.id,d.mth
from member m,(select 1 mth union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) d
) due
left join payment p on p.mem_id = due.id and p.mth = due.mth
where p.mth is null
group by due.id
) due on paid.id = due.id
```

You get this

```
+------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+
| id   | mthspaid | NoofMthsPaid | NoofMthsMissed | mthsmissed |
+------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+
|    1 | 1,2,3,4  |            4 |              0 | NULL       |
|    2 | 1,3      |            2 |              2 | 2,4        |
|    3 | 2,4      |            2 |              2 | 1,3        |
|    4 | NULL     |            0 |              4 | 1,2,3,4    |
+------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```